# Do probabilities that don't vary much from the average contribute to greater entropy?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

If the entropy of information reaches its maximum when all values of X are equally probable, indicating maximum uncertainty, do probabilities that don't vary much from the average contribute to greater entropy?

Comment: Can you please explain how this is related to AI? I know that this can be related to AI but it might not. So, please, provide more info about why you're asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite set of possibilities (such as 0/1 for binary), the entropy is maximized, given that the probability of observing one or the other is 0.5, and nothing can increase it further

If you have a distribution that is close to the uniform, your entropy is high, but it's not maximized